# Parse matched items by regex not containing specific strings

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0

I have the following codes to parse text file to get matched items:

```
$content = Get-Content "InputFile.txt"
$pattern = "(?<item>[^\[\]]+)"
$found = $pattern.Matches($content)
$found | Select-Object -Property @{Expression={$_.Groups['item']}; Label='Items' | ft
```

So far so good. The above codes will get all items matching [...] pattern (or items withing [ and ] brackets) from input file.

Example content of input file:

```
something [item1] and then [item2abc]....
```

The parsed result is

```
Items
------
item1
item2abc
....
```

Now I want to filter found items not containing specific strings, such as "abc" as ending. Not sure how to update my pattern to find all items without "abc" ending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using Replace to filter out "abc"?

Your codes:

```
 ....
 $found | Select-Object -Property @{Expression={$_.Groups['item'] `
   -Replace 'abc$', '' # Add this `
   }; Label='Items' | ft
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have a specific string that you want to not allow at the end you can matcha regex like this (warning, it's ugly, but not matching certain strings is something regexes are bad at.):

```
.*[^a][^b][^c]$
```

for disallowing strings ending in `abc`

Comment: Or simply `.*(?<!abc)$` See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#grouping_constructs

Comment: Good point, i didn't thing of a negative lookbehind since it was at the end of the string, my mistake!! :)